# Como fechar todas as conexões ativas?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Tenho 8 conexões abertas no banco de dados e gostaria de encerrar todas elas, é possível?

Qual é o comando do MySQL que faz isso?

Comment: Não funciona o mysql_close() ?

Comment: posta o código que você abre a conexão com MySQL

Comment: O que exatamente voce quer fazer?

Comment: Eu queria fazer isso dando um comando no banco e não por código, estou usando o workbanch

Comment: `mysql_close()` assim como `mysql_` está DEPRECATED, se for utilizar coloque `mysqli_*` no lugar

Comment: Alguns sistemas fazem conexões persistentes ou tenta reconectar todas vezes que o sistema perde a conexão, fique atento para isso.

Comment: Não tenho como testar, então não posso escrever uma resposta com isso, mas vale dar uma olhada https://www.percona.com/blog/2009/05/21/mass-killing-of-mysql-connections/

Comment: o mysql_close() não está rodando

Comment: Cadê a tag falando que o assunto é sobre PHP? Forneça mais detalhes sobre a linguagem que você está utilizando, isso é importante para quem for ler a pergunta e ter que dar uma resposta. Ou mesmo é importante para quem vai ter sua dúvida

Comment: Não tem nada haver com PHP. O OP quer apenas desconectar tudo mundo de uma vez so. um restart resolve :P hehe

Comment: isso mesmo rray, eu só quero derrubar todas as conexões, independente de sistema

Comment: @LucasSousa Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 6):

Não existe diretamente mas é possível fazer isto. Execute isto no MySQL:

```
select concat('KILL ',id,';') from information_schema.processlist where user='root' into outfile '/tmp/a.txt';
```

depois

```
source /tmp/a.txt;
```

[Fonte](https://www.percona.com/blog/2009/05/21/mass-killing-of-mysql-connections/).

[Documentação do KILL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/kill.html).

Também dá ra fazer isto:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('KILL QUERY ',id,';') SEPARATOR ' ') KillQuery
FROM information_schema.processlist WHERE user<>'system user'\G
```

[Fonte](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/2637/41).

Para rodar na linha de comando:

```
mysql -NBe "SELECT CONCAT('KILL ', id, ';') FROM information_schema.processlist WHERE user = 'some_username';" | mysql -vv
```

[Fonte](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/7444/41).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/DML/CloseConnections.sql).

Comment: no source está dando erro de sintax

Comment: Neste [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9938302/3155576) mostra como executar sem salvar em arquivo mas sim usando variáveis.

Comment: Tem outras opções. Veja no *link* da fonte se está fazendo igual.

Comment: são dois comandos separados @LucasSousa, execute um e na sequência execute o outro